# How to get a value from database firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in firebase and I am trying to set the score value to 500 in kotlin code, but I do not know how to change it because it has a push key and a authentication `uid` key, how do I change the value of the score to 500? If you want you can check the image description below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `updateChildren()` to update the field:

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
val uid = user.uid
val key = database.child("Users").child(uid).push().key
```

Before updating you need to have the value of the push key and uid. Therefore when storing the data, you can use `val key = database.child("Users").child(uid).push().key` to store the value of the `push()` inside a variable. Then later you can update by doing the following:

```
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
val myRef = database.getReference("Users").child(uid).child(key)

val childUpdates = HashMap<String, Any>()
    childUpdates["score"] = 500

    myRef.updateChildren(childUpdates)
```

You can read here for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Comment: but how do I get the specific push kkey to update the children? I just tried this and it creates another key with a child value of score in it but it does not update the key I had before